# Frozen table column not working seemlessly in pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a frozen left column of a HTML table. I tried various methods suggested on STO but none of them suited to me. Then I re-created it by using 2 same style HTML tables. Though, I got somewhat success but its not perfect yet. I can't get on with it to fix it. I want to stick to pure CSS to achieve it.

Here's my code in action:

```css
 #tb_wrapper {
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  max-width:960px;
 }
 
 #fixed_tb_wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:99999;
 }
 
 #scrollable_tb_wrapper {
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  z-index:-99999;
 }
 
 .tb_records1 {
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0;
  text-align:center;
 }
 
 .tb_records1 th {
  background-color:#5F5F5F;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .tb_records1 th, .tb_records1 td {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 
 .tb_records1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
 }
 
 .tb_records1 tr:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
 }

 .tb_responsive {
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
 }

 .tb_records2 {
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:100%;
 }
 
 .tb_records2 th {
  background-color:#5F5F5F;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .tb_records2 th, .tb_records2 td {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 
 .tb_records2 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
 }
 
 .tb_records2 tr:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="tb_wrapper">

        <div id="fixed_tb_wrapper" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <table class="tb_records1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Post ID</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>This is a long Post ID</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="scrollable_tb_wrapper" style="border:1px solid blue;">
            <div class="tb_responsive">
                <table class="tb_records2">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Post Name</th>
                        <th>Post URL</th>
                        <th>Post Title</th>
                        <th>Post Heading</th>
                        <th>Post Content</th>
                        <th>Post Date Published</th>
                        <th>Post Date Modified</th>
                        <th>Post Image</th>
                        <th>Post Views</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>my-post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>My Post</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                        <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                        <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                        <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

You can see that the first table which has a single column Post ID is fixed and the right table scrolls through under it. But I am having 2 issues:

1. The content of scrollable table is visible under first fixed table (column). I used z-index but it has no effect. Don't know why?
2. Is it necessary to give fixed width to first fixed table? And then equal left-margin to the right scrollable table? If so then, then it seems working but will that be the only best solution?

Answer (score 1):

> A pure CSS solutions

**Solution 1**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

td, th {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 5em;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top: -1px;
  /*compensate for top border*/
}

.headcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}

.long {
  background: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
        <tr><th class="headcol">1</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">2</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">3</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">4</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">5</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">6</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**Solution 2**

```css
.container {
   /* Attach fixed-th-table to this container,
      in order to layout fixed-th-table
      in the same way as scolled-td-table" */
   position: relative;
    
   /* Truncate fixed-th-table */
   overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed-th-table-wrapper td,
.fixed-th-table-wrapper th,
.scrolled-td-table-wrapper td,
.scrolled-td-table-wrapper th {
   /* Set background to non-transparent color
      because two tables are one above another.
    */
   background: white;
}
.fixed-th-table-wrapper {
   /* Make table out of flow */
   position: absolute;
}
.fixed-th-table-wrapper th {
    /* Place fixed-th-table th-cells above 
       scrolled-td-table td-cells.
     */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.scrolled-td-table-wrapper td {
    /* Place scrolled-td-table td-cells
       above fixed-th-table.
     */
    position: relative;
}
.scrolled-td-table-wrapper {
   /* Make horizonal scrollbar if needed */
   overflow-x: auto;
}


/* Simulating border-collapse: collapse,
   because fixed-th-table borders
   are below ".scrolling-td-wrapper table" borders
*/

table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td, th {
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}
th:first-child {
   border-left-width: 1px;
}
tr:last-child td,
tr:last-child th {
   border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

/* Unimportant styles */

.container {
    width: 250px;
}
td, th {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
<div class="fixed-th-table-wrapper">
<!-- fixed-th-table -->
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>aaaaaaa</th>
         <td>ccccccccccc asdsad asd as</td>
         <td>ccccccccccc asdsad asd as</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <th>cccccccc</th>
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzzzz</td>
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzzzz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
    
<div class="scrolled-td-table-wrapper">
<!-- scrolled-td-table
     - same as fixed-th-table -->
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>aaaaaaa</th>
         <td>ccccccccccc asdsad asd as</td>
         <td>ccccccccccc asdsad asd as</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <th>cccccccc</th>
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzzzz</td>
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzzzz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: You just pasted your own code solution here. It would be better if you fix my code.

Comment: Dear! Your approach is not valid as this cannot be done by your code structure. I let you know why because position absolution cant fixed elements at all.

Comment: But some STO users have suggested this kind of approach to achieve sticky column.

Comment: Then may be he is right but as far as i know, we had to avoid this approach, Any way here is a fix of your code just add `margin` or `padding` equal to the size of absolute table like in your mention example case i add `padding:154px` like this `#scrollable_tb_wrapper {    border: 1px solid #cccccc;    z-index: -99999;  padding-left: 153px;}` and it worked.

Comment: What is the disadvantage in my approach?

Comment: @user5307298 Not that much other then line of code you can do this with one table only easily while you are using 2 tables with lot of extra styles. But i repeat its up to your ease of doing...

Comment: But you are also using two tables in your second solution!

Comment: Yes i told you i prefer using one but as you can see second solution is the closest one of yours. I just remove some extra divs